# Wait For Batch Subroutine Label to finish before doing more work

Tags: batch-file

Unrelated to running other batch files or other executables.  I have subroutines in my batch file and a main method which calls them.  I put `echo`s after each call to a subroutine and the numbers aren't hitting when I expect.  It doesn't seem to be executing sequentially.

```
call :_beginProject %subProject%
echo 1
call :_renameBasicFile Service
echo 2
call :_renameBasicFile Test
echo 3
call :_endProject
echo 4

pause
exit /b

:_beginProject
echo in begin project
Do Other Things

:_renameBasicFile 
echo in rename file
Do Other Things

:_endProject
echo in end project
Do Other Things
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought `exit /b` meant something else.  Turns out what was happening, but wasn't clear, is that when I called _beginProject, ALL Code from _beginProject down was executing, like a switch with no breaks.  `exit /b` is like a break from the current stack of processing.  So when you call into a function, you push to a new execution stack, and you need to pop it with `exit /b`, or you'll execute to the end of the file.  So I had to change to this to return control to the calling stack after each label/subroutine:

```
call :_beginProject %subProject%
echo 1
call :_renameBasicFile Service
echo 2
call :_renameBasicFile Test
echo 3
call :_endProject
echo 4

pause
exit /b

:_beginProject
echo in begin project
Do Other Things
exit /b

:_renameBasicFile 
echo in rename file
Do Other Things
exit /b

:_endProject
echo in end project
Do Other Things
exit /b
```

Comment: `GoTo :EOF` is an often used alternative.

Comment: If you don't include an `exit /B` command to mark the end of _each_ subroutine, how the Batch file processor could know that? **`:/`**

Comment: Yes.  All you had to do was search SO for the `CALL` command and read a few posts.  Would have saved you the time and trouble of posting a question and answer.

Comment: @Aacini I assumed the processor would see the End of File, or another subroutine definition such as `:something`, and know it was done.  I was being spoiled by languages with function scopes.  So I assume anybody else who rarely works with batch but has scope engrained in their brain would feel the same way.

Comment: How the processor would know that `:something` is the start of another subroutine and not just a target label for a `goto` command? (I am not being annoying, just aiding you to think logically **`;)`**